# Calling 3rd party's rest api embedded with p12 certificate

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, call

I’ve been searching for days but couldn’t find a solution. I have an API written in C#. I have to call 3rd party’s rest API from an URL with JSON input but I have to use 3rd party’s p12 certificate in order to call their API.

I found some codes, I tried all of them but I couldn’t achieve.

1. Should I install p12 certificate to my local machine’s (or to any server which calls the 3rd party API) Trusted Store or it is OK to embed it into the “api caller” code? (I have already installed to may local machine)
2. Below code raise that error:

   > {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."}

```
      string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GivenApiUrl"];
      var certFile = Path.Combine(@"Given P12 certificate path", " Given_P12_certificate_name.p12");
    
      X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "password");

      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
      request.Timeout = 20000;
      request.ContentType = "application/json";
      request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
      request.UserAgent = "TEST";
      request.Method = "POST";

      using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requ.GetRequestStream()))
      {
    string json = "{\"Check\":{\"Id\":\"Tst123\",\"Tkn\":{\"Id\":\"ABCDEFG\"},\"Obj\":\"123456\"}}";
    streamWriter.Write(json);
      }
     
      HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Would you please help me?

I need to call 3rd party's API with P12 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution myself:

I setup p12 certificate file to my local machine’s (the machine which calls the 3rd party api) Trust Store (I am not sure whether it was necessary or not) and the succesfuly running code is :

```
string "3rd party url here";
var certFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\certificate path here", 
"certificate_name.p12");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "password");
var clientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { cert };

var options = new RestClientOptions(URL)
{
ClientCertificates = clientCertificates
};

var client = new RestClient(options); //This the way to add certificate 
                                        to RestClient

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

var restRequest = new RestRequest();

restRequest.Method = Method.Post;

restRequest.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
Request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

string json = "{\"xxxxx\":{\"yyyyy\":\"Blablabla\",\"zzzzz\": 
   {\"wwwww\":\"Blablabla\"},\"qqqqq\":\" Blablabla \"}}";  // My json input here

restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(restrequest);
```